# Composer require dependencies and version issue. Is it possible to force or change satisfiable version requirements?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am currently working in Laravel 5.6.
I am trying to use the Corcel composer package.
It looks like I already have a version of the hautelook/phpass installed and locked at 0.3.5.  Corcel seams to want 0.3.4. Is there a way to force Corcel ge to use 0.3.5 so I don't have to play with my lock?

---

From my terminal:

> $ composer require jgrossi/corcel Using version ^2.6 for
> jgrossi/corcel ./composer.json has been updated Loading composer
> repositories with package information Updating dependencies (including
> require-dev) Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable
> set of packages.

Problem 1

---

> - Installation request for hautelook/phpass (locked at 0.3.5) -> satisfiable by hautelook/phpass[0.3.5].
>
>   - jgrossi/corcel 2.6.x-dev requires hautelook/phpass 0.3.4 -> satisfiable by hautelook/phpass[0.3.4].
>   - jgrossi/corcel v2.6.0 requires hautelook/phpass 0.3.4 -> satisfiable by hautelook/phpass[0.3.4].
>   - jgrossi/corcel v2.6.1 requires hautelook/phpass 0.3.4 -> satisfiable by hautelook/phpass[0.3.4].
>   - jgrossi/corcel v2.6.2 requires hautelook/phpass 0.3.4 -> satisfiable by hautelook/phpass[0.3.4].
>   - Conclusion: don't install hautelook/phpass 0.3.4
>   - Installation request for jgrossi/corcel ^2.6 -> satisfiable by jgrossi/corcel[2.6.x-dev, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2].

Installation failed, reverting `./composer.json` to its original content.

**Update:**
moving forward when I run into version issues in a composer package I typically fork the repo, make my edits and use my repo in place until the original developer gets a chance to update.

Jeffery Way has a great tutorial on it here
[https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-8/episodes/11][1]
[1]: https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-8/episodes/11

Comment: Is it possible to update the existing composer.json to a newer version of phpass?

Comment: You can fake a library version using "as" in composer. https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md

Comment: Thank you,   and thank you for the formatting to my post!